# Is usage of unary operators like + and !! as type conversion idiom acceptable by some well-known C++ code convention?

Tags: c++

In this question I do not ask about someones subjective opinion - rather asking link to modern C++ document.

Especially in legacy C/C++ code we can encounter extensive usage of logical unary operators as shortcuts for type conversion, say **!**:

```
if(!finished) {/**/}
```

-

```
if(!!count == true) {/**/}
```

last one was likely introduced to eliminate compiler's warning (C4805: '==': unsafe mix of type 'int' and type 'bool' in operation).

Or **+** for promoting result to integer:

```
std::cout << "uchar: "
              << + std::numeric_limits<unsigned char>::lowest();
```

From the other side references and conventions recommend avoiding such constructs that relies on conversions of integer to booleans and instead of shortened **if(count)** verbosely write "more readable":

```
if(count == true) {/**/}
```

Is usage of unary operators like **+**, **!** and **!!** as type conversion idiom acceptable by some well-known modern C++ code convention (like [Google C++ Style Guide](https://google.github.io/styleguide/cppguide.html), etc) in comparison with more explicit but verbose **static_cast**? If yes, please refer to such publicly available code convention.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194853/discussion-on-question-by-koh-i-nor-is-usage-of-unary-operators-like-and-as).

Comment: Double-negation is more idiomatically used when we want all true values to count as `1`.  A more realistic example is `total += !!count`.  (Not an answer, as I'm not referencing any style guide here, just common practice).